# The panel is expanded when removing/adding components to it

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

When I provide this code to `mouseClicked` method in `MouseListener` interface,
the `changeableContentPanel` is expanded. Could anyone help me?

```
if (!changeableContentPanel.isAncestorOf(aMO)) {
    aMO = new AccountsManagementOptions();
    changeableContentPanel.removeAll();                
    changeableContentPanel.validate();
    changeableContentPanel.repaint();
    aMO.setLocation(5, 100);
    changeableContentPanel.add(aMO);
    changeableContentPanel.validate();
    changeableContentPanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove/add components to the panel you should be using:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

That is you should be using revalidate() instead of validate() and you only need to invoke the code once after all changes to the panel have been made.

> the changeableContentPanel is expanded.

Yes, because the layout manager is invoked and the size of the panel will recalculated based on the size of the component added to the panel.

> Could anyone help me?

If you don't want the size to change then you should be using a `CardLayout` on your panel. The panel size will be fixed to the size of the largest card added to the panel. Then you just swap components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: If I understand the problem then yes it will work with a CardLayout. You are using the layout incorrectly or you have other layout issues. Read the tutorial and download the demo code to do a test.  Post your [mcve] if you still have problems.